# SPSS: how to find the relation between two variable in spss

Tags: statistics, spss

I have a datasets related to some patients. The datasets consist of many information regarding the blood work has been done couple times for patients (before treatment and after treatment). After doing survival analysis using Kaplan Meir method, we realized that high phosphate (hyperphosphatemia[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HhI2e.png) ) and high GFR (Kidney's variable[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/plX11.png)) will cause the death . Now I want to know if there is any relation between these two? meaning that for example high GFR will cause the high phosphate? or each act independently? can anyone help me to figure out how to do this in SPSS?[Sample od dataset image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/po0j5.png)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since both of these are being used as categorical variables in the analysis you showed results from, the CROSSTABS procedure would seem useful to assess association. It has tests and various measures of association available.